# Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 Error : NO such file or directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

I get a error from the Xcode as below:

clang: error: no such file or directory: **'/Users/Ashok/Desktop/projectdir/AScommon/View Support/GradientView.m'**

clang: error: **no input files
Command**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

---

***The main thing is that file/directory path shown above doesnot exists in my mac.***

*Have tried with the following:*

I even set the paths in the Build setting **search paths.**

I have tried all the methods of cleaning the project,
reopening of the xcode, clearing the derived data.

Can anybody please guide me the solutions, so the app will built without errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with search paths; that source file must be part of your project.  Missing files normally appear in red... do you see any? (try expanding all groups in the project)

Comment: Earlier I had seen them, but now I have set them and dont see the red in the files. Actually the path users/Ashok..... doesnot exists in my system. I dont know from where this is referred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it happens like this.May GradientView.m exists in your target location, just check whether it is available in your project and its color should not be red. If it is red then select that file and delete that file.And again add it by Right click on your project > Add files to "Your project" > add again GradientView.m file. Then Product > clean and built > run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because your project > target > Build Phases > Compile Sources is trying to compile a file that doesn't exist. Please check if GradientView.m exists according to above step.

Comment: GradientView.m exists in the project folder, and I have even set the location of the file, but still getting the error.